# Stop RegEx everytime in finds a certain string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3. 
I have a large text file with the 48 Laws of Power, I want to set it up to email one law at a time to a friend of mine, so I need to break them up in one "chapter" at a time in a list using `re.findall()`.

Each chapter starts with Law 1, Law 2, Law 36 etc. Is there any way with regular expressions I can have it match Law and stop matching at the second occurrence of Law?

When I try something like the `list=re.findall(r'(Law.+)Law)` it just puts the entire text file into list[0].

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

```
Law [0-9](.*?)(Law [0-9])+
```

Any Chance this might help you get along the right track?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
matches = re.split('Law [0-9]+', data)
chapters = matches[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^Law \d+.*?(?=Law \d|\Z)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S0oDcy/1)